# Unidirectional many-to-many behavior and needed entities in Doctrine/Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So, i have the following structure of entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Group
{
  /**
   * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection $permissions
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permission")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="group_has_permission",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   * )
   */
  protected $permissions;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->permissions = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Permission {}
```

It's just an example, but i'm confused. I need another entity probably called "group_has_permission" with two fields: group_id and permission_id, right? Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new entity.

Doctrine will create for you a group table, a permission table & a join table in order to link a group to multiple permissions. This is transparent for you.

Comment: That's amazing. So, the names can be anything?

Comment: Yes, you can give the name you want

Comment: I'm getting various SQL syntax errors when running the above code on schema:create. Any ideas?

Comment: Your entity must have an id and follow the PSR-0 (you can not define two class in the same php file)